# Using a custom LC-3 trap routine

Tags: lc3, lc3-trap

I wrote a subroutine to be used as a Trap call via Trap x26. My code for my subroutine is at address x3300. I cannot figure out how to jump from x26 to my actual instructions for the subroutine at x3300, since the gap is greater than JSR's PC offset parameter allows. I know I could add some code in near x26  to make it possible to jump all the way to x3300, but I don't think that's how I am supposed to do it. I think I'm missing something with understanding traps in general.

Here's my understanding/confusion of traps: So from x0000 - X00FF is the trap vector table. For example, if you call `TRAP x20`, then the PC goes to x20 and continues execution with the instruction at x20. (Please let me know if this is incorrect!) At this point I am confused because at the address x20 in the LC-3 is a `BRZ x0021` command, which takes the PC to x21. At x21, there is a `BRZ x52`command. When this branch gets executed to go to x52 plus the PC, the command there is `TRAP x00`. Most of the Trap 20's commands seem to go to these (what look like) nonsense trap commands. After the trap x00 is executed, the program goes to xFD79. This is really confusing me since at x00 in memory, there is just another `TRAP x00`. To me, it seems like the program should go to x00 instead of xFD79.

Can someone help explain this to me please? What exactly is going on when a trap is called? I thought it just went to another address in memory where the actual code for the instruction was and executed that, but what I have seen doesn't reflect that. Any help is greatly appreciated as this is preventing me from completing a school project right now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"So from x0000 - X00FF is the trap vector table. For example, if you call TRAP x20, then the PC goes to x20 and continues execution with the instruction at x20. (Please let me know if this is incorrect!)"

This is correct, however the next sentence...

"At this point I am confused because at the address x20 in the LC-3 is a BRZ x0021 command, which takes the PC to x21"

The command you see which looks like a BRz is not, in fact, an instruction. It is an address! x0400 would be a fairly useless command - it the PC offset is zero, so it just goes to the next line. If you interpret it as an address instead, and go to that address as part of the trap call, you will find the rest of the trap instructions.